# Join operation not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have three tables tbA and tbB

tbA

- tbAId
- tbAName

tbB

- tbBId
- tbBName

tbC

- tbCId
- tbAId
- tbBId

Now I have to fetch all BName assigned to tbA

I have tried like

```
SELECT   
L.tbBId L.tbBName FROM tbB L
JOIN
tbC P ON P.tbAId = @AId;
```

Please help me!!!

Comment: Now I have to do magic?

Comment: The suspense is killing me!!

Comment: It would be better if you present it with example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
SELECT L.tbBId,
       L.tbBName
FROM   tbB L
       JOIN tbC P
         ON P.tbBId = L.tbBId
       JOIN tbA A
         ON P.tbAId = A.tbAId
WHERE  P.tbAId = @AId;
```

Comment: @Nida This answer is as you expected but I (or may be others also) request to do some google before posting question because this thing can easily be found.

Answer (score 1):

```
select tbAId,tbAName,tbBName
from tbA join tbC
on tbA.tbAId=tbC.tbAId
join tbB
on tbB.tbBId=tbC.tbBId
WHERE  P.tbAId = @AId
```

Answer (score 1):

Corrections that you need to change

**1.** you have not separated two columns by comma

```
L.tbBId L.tbBName
```

**2.** you have not considered table tbA in the query & you are putting `tbAId` in the query

Here is the changed query. I think this will help you

```
SELECT 
    L.tbBId,
    L.tbBName
FROM
    tbB L
INNER JOIN 
    tbC P ON P.tbBId = L.tbBId
INNER JOIN 
    tbA A ON P.tbAId = A.tbAId
WHERE  
    P.tbAId = @AId;
```